# Add a column count in a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to achieve a strange query. I have a table like this:

table People

```
-----------------------
| id | name | family |
+----+------+--------+
| 1  |  Bob |  Smith |
+----+------+--------+
| 2  |  Joe | Smith  |
----------------------
```

I want to return an assoc array like this

```
id : 1
name : bob
family : smith
familySize : 2
```

So something like this

```
"SELECT id, name, family, familySize FROM People"
```

How can I get the familySize in there? Keep in mind my query may have many families and I want them all to be returned.

Thank you.

Comment: Use MySQL's `COUNT()` aggregate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above 2 answers won't work with multiple families.

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT id, name, family, familySize FROM People p1
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as familySize, family FROM People GROUP BY family) p2
USING(family)
```

Comment: *"The above 2 answers won't work with multiple families."* - I don't think yours will neither. I doubt OP has a column called `familySize`.

Comment: My answer doesn't expect a column called familySize.

Comment: What do you call this then `SELECT id, name, family, familySize` <=?

Comment: Believe me, I have. What is it that I'm not grasping?

Comment: "JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as familySize, family FROM People GROUP BY family) p2"

Comment: It's a method I don't know about; I stand corrected then. The initial select threw me off.

Comment: Although I altered the query a bit to also search from another table (and it works) I seem to get no results if COUNT returns 0 for a column. IE if I do a regular query, and JOIN with some COUNT() to another table that returns 0, nothing at all is return.ed

Comment: JOIN (aka INNER JOIN) requires results in both tables, so when joining to itself you know for certain there are results. LEFT JOIN will return the first result even if there are no results on the subsequent query; I hope that makes sense, I'm having trouble wording it.

Comment: Oh awesome.. Easy as LEFT JOIN. Thank yuo!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

SELECT id, name, family, count(id) as familySize FROM People

Answer (score 1):

```
     "SELECT id, name, family, count(family) as familySize FROM People group by   
      family"
```

Comment: I don't think OP has a column called `familySize`

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention here that what if two or three families have the same surname "Smith". It won't give you the desired results.

What I suggest you is while inserting the data in the table assign a family head and all the family members have a field called family_ID has primary key as value of family_head.

This will give you accurate results with 1000's of people. I have made a family portal has over 12k members now and it works fine for me.

Hope it helps.